# How to retrieve Symfony 3's Kernel instance in an application?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-http-kernel

I would like to access Symfony 3's `Kernel.getEnvironment()` in a service implementing the `ContainerAwareTrait`.

I am wondering whether I should implement an instance of the Kernel object or whether one is already created by the application itself. If so, how can I retrieve the instance?

My application is a clone of the Symfony 3 demo application.

Comment: Might be worth reading through the [Symfony Recommended Practices](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/index.html) document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't you just inject `%kernel.environment%` into your service?

Comment: Maybe, but I see in another question that $this->getContainer()->getParameter('kernel.environment'); might work too. What do you think?

Comment: It will, but keeping your dependencies explicit (through the service defintion) is much cleaner

Comment: also, avoiding to use the complete container is kinda a best pratice, especially when all you need is a small information easily injected,